# Button with multiple words as text

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this button in a form:

```
$this->addElement('submit', 'save and next', array(
            'id' => 'next'
            ));
```

But when I render it, the text in the button is all together: `saveandnext`.

Any help?

Comment: Please show the generated HTML markup of the button

Comment: have you tried to escape the spaces with back slash ?

Comment: &nbsp; is that requried?

Comment: @DaveRandom i added `'label' => 'save and next'` and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the text in label, it should work.

```
$this->addElement('submit', 'save and next', array(
    'id' => 'next',
    'label' => 'Save and Next'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do some thing like this

```
  $save_next = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit(FORM_BUTTON_PREFIX . 'save_next', array(
                                                            'class'     => 'btnSubmit save_next',
                                                            'label'     => 'Save & Next',
                                                            'ignore'    => true
                                                    ));
            $save_next->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
            $this->addElement($save_next);
```